# Launch Telegram app from Android application with message and recipient

Tags: java, android, telegram

I need to open Telegram from my own Android App prepopulating both the message and recipient (and not having to choose betwenn Chrome or Telegram),
I achieved the first one with this code:

```
        final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
        Intent tIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        tIntent.setType("text/plain");
        tIntent.setPackage(appName);
        tIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
        mUIActivity.startActivity(tIntent);
```

And the second one with this code:

```
        Intent tIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        tIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://telegram.me/USERID"));
        startActivity(tIntent);
```

(I removed all checks like isTelegramInstalled for simplicity)

I tried to mix the two methods 
adding some intent extra such as msg we get to this code that will open Telegram, in one click, with pre-populated message and recipient:

```
        Intent telegramIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        tIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://telegram.me/username"), "text/plain");
        final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
        tIntent.setPackage(appName);
        tIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
        startActivity(tIntent);
```

...aaand it didn't work!

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=http://telegram.me/... flg=0x1 pkg=org.telegram.messenger clip={null T:hello} (has extras) }`

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=http://telegram.me/... flg=0x1 pkg=org.telegram.messenger clip={null T:hello} (has extras) }
```

Telegram chat activity class has a different name and you pass other activity name.

**Find which class use telegram for chat activity and pass it on set package method**

Comment: It's weird because both my first and second code works, but not when I try  fo do an `Intent.ACTION_SEND` with `Uri.parse` of the telegram url

Answer (score 0):

Please try below function for open Telegram

```
public static void openTelegram(Activity activity, String userName) {
    Intent general = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.com/" + userName));
    HashSet<String> generalResolvers = new HashSet<>();
    List<ResolveInfo> generalResolveInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(general, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : generalResolveInfo) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName != null) {
            generalResolvers.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
    }

    Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/" + userName));
    int goodResolver = 0;
    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(telegram, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName != null && !generalResolvers.contains(info.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                goodResolver++;
                telegram.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO: if there are several good resolvers create custom chooser
    if (goodResolver != 1) {
        telegram.setPackage(null);
    }
    if (telegram.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivity(telegram);
    }
}
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: I need to add a message, not only open the chat with a specified username. How can this be achieved with your code?

Comment: May be your code is correct but you have not telegram messenger app so it saws error.

Comment: I do have the telegram app, as I wrote the first two codes work, but either I can add a recipient or a message, not both